# UIviewを内包した配列においてframeのx,yについて昇順で並び替える方法

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, iphone, swift4

swift4でUIviewを内包した配列においてframeのx,yについて昇順で並び替える方法はどうすればよいでしょうか

viewcontrollerにおいて

```
var array = [UIView]()
func viewDidLoad() {
    for i in 0...8 {
        for n in 0...4 {
            let view = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 3 * n, y: 3* i, width: 10, height: 10)
            view.tag = (Int(i) + 1) * 10 + (1 * Int(n) + 1)        
            self.array.append(view)
            self.view.addSubview(view)
        }
    } 
}
```

というコードを書いた後に

```
self.array[4].frame = self.allyArray[7].frame
self.array[7].frame = self.allyArray[4].frame
```

のようにUIviewが画面内で移動を繰り返すとします。

このような場合、array内のUIviewの並びがframeのyで昇順し、さらにxで昇順する場合どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のコードを適時実行すると行けると思います。
お試しください。

```
    self.array.sort{
        (view1 : UIView, view2 : UIView) -> Bool in
        if(view1.frame.origin.y == view2.frame.origin.y)
        {
            return view1.frame.origin.x < view2.frame.origin.x
        }

        return view1.frame.origin.y < view2.frame.origin.y
    }
```